# Django trigger add on models

Tags: python, django, django-models

In adminsite, I want if the user create an account on Student table, it will also add to the dashboard table, how can i do that?

```
class Dashboard(models.Model):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())


class Student(models.Model):
    Gender = [
        ('Male', 'Male'),
        ('Female', 'Female')
    ]
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=500,  null=True, default='Student')
    contact_number = models.IntegerField(max_length=50,   null=True)
    age = models.IntegerField( null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Gender,  null=True)
    birthdate = models.DateField(max_length=50,  null=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "LIST OF STUDENTS"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could overwrite the `save` method of class `Student` like e.g. so:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    Gender = [
        ('Male', 'Male'),
        ('Female', 'Female')
    ]
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=500,  null=True, default='Student')
    contact_number = models.IntegerField(max_length=50,   null=True)
    age = models.IntegerField( null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Gender,  null=True)
    birthdate = models.DateField(max_length=50,  null=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "LIST OF STUDENTS"

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # Create a new Dashboard instance
        Dashboard.objects.get_or_create(
            fullname=args,  # Pass your desired values to the save method
            status=args  # Pass your desired values to the save method
        )
        print('New Student and Dashboard instance created')
        # Run save method on Student instance
        super(Student, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Note that `get_or_create` could be replaced with any other creation approach of a new dashboard approach. Now whenever you create and save a student instance the code inside its `save` method is executed accordingly.

Comment: Hi @JSRB, i copy your code and i receive this error `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'save'` this error is from this line of code `super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: @ClaireAnnVargas ah it is supposed to be `super(Student, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` -- fixed it

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in many ways, I would suggest you to use signals, Django provides us with post_save signal. The signals helps us to have a clearer and decoupled implementation.

Your student class will remain as it is

```
class Student:
    <...attributes_here...>
```

you can create a listeners.py and define a listener for Student save action

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Student)
def create_dashboard_on_student_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # note - you have the student instance here, you can use it's values

    if not created:
        return

    Dashboard.objects.get_or_create(
        fullname=<value>,
        status=<value>
    )
```

Please use this as ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/signals/ to implement signals.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way of implement this is using [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/signals/#post-save). In this case use *post_save* method.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Student)
def create_dashboard_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
      Dashboard.objects.create(fullname=instance, status=instance)
    else:
      pass
```

I recommend read this [article](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html). It helped me to understand better how signals work.